# Android emulator no internet

Tags: android, emulation

My Android emulator have no internet connection but my broadband internet connection works perfectly. For information, my emulator used to work and this problem occurs suddenly. 1 month ago it running perfectly. For this, I cant connect my project to Firebase

I reset it & also created a new device but problem not going.
Android studio version - 4.0.1. SDK API 29, Pixel 2 - Android 10.
How can i connect internet in my emulator?
[Here is my emulator showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAsSN.png)

Comment: have you got some proxy or vpn?

Comment: If you have any questions please put them in your post.

Comment: No....i'm not using any vpn

Comment: even i had this issue...i downloaded another emulator..... or try using real device

Comment: Turn Wi-Fi off in your emulator, does it work now?

Comment: No. it doesn't it work

Comment: The emulator uses your host's computer networking, so the connection between your emulator and your computer is somehow failing to talk to the network. Please update your question to include your operating system, versions, things you have tried, etc. It's not possible to guess out of thin air.